# Inheritance : does not contain a definition for and no extension method accepting a first argument

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
abstract class Parent
{
        protected string attrParent;

        public AttrParent { get; protected set }

        public Parent(string sParent)
        {
            AttrParent = sParent;
        }
}

class Child : Parent
{
        private string attrChild;

        public AttrChild { get; private set }

        public Child(string sParent, string sChild) : base(sParent)
        {
            AttrChild = sChild;
        }
}

class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parent p = new Child();

            p.AttrChild = "hello";
        }
}
```

When I run this program, I get the following error :

> 'Example.Parent' does not contain a definition for 'AttrChild' and no extension method 'AttrChild' accepting a first argument of type 'Example.Parent'"

Can anybody explain why this is?

Comment: *"When I run this program"* What do you mean? Does it even compile?

Comment: Make `AttrChild` public like this `public AttrChild { get;  set; }`. And change the variable `p` type to `Child`.

Comment: You might be *creating* an instance of `Child` - but your variable `p` only looks at the parts of `Child` that are already present in `Parent` (since you've defined its type to be `Parent`) .... and there's no `AttrChild` in the `Parent` class

Comment: No, it doesn't. When I press F5

Comment: Also, there is no parameterless constructor in `Child`. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you assign `Child` instance to variable typed as `Parent` you can only access members declared on `Parent`.

You'd have to downcast it back to `Child` to access `Child`-only members:

```
Parent p = new Child();

Child c = (Child)p;
c.AttrChild = "hello";
```

That cast might fail at runtime, because there might be a different class that inherits `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

A `parent` instance can only access methods avaliable in the `parent` class, If you want to access the `child` methods you need to create a `child` class. The problem if that you are trying to access the `child` methods from the `parent` class.

With inheritance if you wish to call methods in the `child` class you will need to make a new instance of `child` class. The purpose of that a `parent` can have multiple `child` classes inheriting from it and if the code in your example worked then it would cause problems when a `parent` has multiple `child` classes.