# Compiler doesn't recognize a property

Tags: c#, oop, console-application

I have two classes `Human` and `Employee`
`Employee` inherits `Human` as shown,
`Human` has two properties (`name` and `age`),
`Employee` has two properties (`age` and `salary`)

When I try to create an instance from `Human` in one line definition it see all the `Human` and `Employee` properties
But, when I split the definition it see only `Human` properties and throws an error on `Employee` properties!

I don't understand why this happens

Here is my code:

```
public class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Human
{
    public new int Age { get; set; } 
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Human h = new Employee { Name = "Ahmed", Age = 24, Salary = 1500 };

        Human h2 = new Employee();
        h2.Name = "Ahmed";
        h2.Age = 10;
        h2.Salary = 5000; // h.salary has a red underline
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a question about how the concept of inheritance and the concept of polymorphism works in object oriented language. The question is too broad and out of scope for stack overflow.

Comment: you shouldn't need `new Age`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance : does not contain a definition for and no extension method accepting a first argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987564/inheritance-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-and-no-extension-method-acceptin).  The applicable compiler error is CS1061 "'Human' does not contain a definition for 'salary' and no accessible extension method 'salary' accepting a first argument of type 'Human' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1):

Also `h` *is* actually of the `Employee` type, you told the compiler to thread it as just an instance of a `Human`. To access the salary property either declare `h` as `Employee` or cast `h` as an employee.

```
Employee h = new Employe {...};
//...
h.salary = 5000;

// or
((Employee) h).salary = 5000; //if you know h is an employee

// or
Employee employee = h as Employee
if(employee != null)
    employee.salary = 50000;

// or, if you can use pattern matching
if(h is Employee employee)
    employee.salary = 50000;
```

Answer (score 1):

When your object is cast as the base type of a hierarchy it will only have access to the members available to that particular type. If you want to have access to the `Employee` members, your object needs to be an `Employee` type.

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.salary = 5000; // No issue, the Employee type knows it has a salary
Human human = employee;
human.salary = 2000; // Compilation error, the Human type doesn't know anything about the salary property available to the derived Employee type
```